# Somewhat complex regex in C# can it be done without lookaheads/lookbehinds? If not how with them?

Tags: c#, regex

This is my current regex in C#

```
"(?<name>" + word + @"[ \n]+MODULE-IDENTITY(?<data>[" + anySymbol + @"]*?)::=[ \n]*\{[ \n]*" + "(?<parent>" + word + " " + "(?<oid>" + word
```

Here is a explanation on what everything does, it's not really complex:

- The `?<name>` , `?<data>` etc are just for naming the variables
- The `word` and `anySymbol` are strings where specific symbols are saved.  In `word` it's `\w`, `-`, and `"`.  In `anySymbol` it's almost every character.
- `MODULE-IDENTITY` is the keyword to search for
- the `::=` after `anySymbol + @"]*?)` is the second keyword to look for

Now the complex part comes here in the part after `MODULE-IDENTITY` and before `::=` there can be occurrences of `::=` but they will only appear inside double quotation marks `"in here"`. Now what I want is to ignore those `::=` inside quotation marks anybody got a idea?

Comment: Are you trying to match or extract?

Comment: @merlin2011 both i guess, i get all those matches in a big text and then i extract all the data from those matches

Comment: @l'L'l where exactly?

Comment: You would replace `::=` with `(?:::=)` in your pattern. It essentially means match, but don't capture. so it will see it and skip over it to the next match. Take a look at this example: http://regex101.com/r/wB1qU1/1

Comment: @l'L'l hm but what if there are multiple ::= in qoutation marks or none at all will it work correctly?

Comment: Well, that all depends; I don't know what your original string looks like. But it would likely require something in addition to what I've suggested if you had multiples throughout.

Comment: @Vajura: With any reg ex question its always very useful to put in one or more test strings that people can use to understand the question better as well as to test any potential solutions against.

Comment: @l'L'l i almost got it now i think, modified it a bit now the only thing that is missing is to make the **"[^"]*::=[^"]*"** match multiple times and/or zero times
http://regex101.com/r/wB1qU1/2

Comment: @Chris sorry didnt know i could do this on a website like this
http://regex101.com/r/wB1qU1/2 anyways read my previous comment

Comment: @Vajura: As Chris said, provide test strings and what you want to extract from each of these test strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your regex101 link in the comments I made this regex that can match multiple instances of `::=` in `""` before the `::=` outside of the `""`:

```
IMPORTS(?<data>(?:[^:"]|:(?!:=)|"[^"]*")*)::=
```

I don't quite get how it ties into your original C# code but this should help you on the right track. Basically it is saying this after `IMPORTS`:

- `[^:"]` Any character that **isn't** `:` or `"`
- `|` **OR**
- `:(?!:=)` A `:` that **isn't** *followed* by `:=` (together making `::=` which you don't want to match)
- `|` **OR**
- `"[^"]*"` A `"` followed by anything that isn't `"` (but could very well be `::=`) followed by `"`

That whole thing is than put in a `(?:...)` group that can be repeated 0 or more times, the result of which is captured as `<data>`.

Some general tips:

- You can edit your question, use it! :) add the regex101 link, add the text you're starting with, add the exact match you want to find (not a description, but the **actual** match)
- Avoid using the `.` in favor of using negative classes (`[^...]`)